# Read a file line by line and if condition is met continue reading till end

Tags: shell-script, awk, read

I want to get user prompted date files which are in two different locations and `scp` to another server. This is what I have done so far, I am struggling with reading constants from file and conditioning with if condition .

- path1 (`/nrtrdepath/`) has 1 file
- path2 (`/dcs/arch_05/AUDIT_REPORT/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/`) 2 files

all files should `scp` to one location

---

**updated** code

```
#=================================
#description     :This script will scp user prompted SL audit files to another SCP /tmp/SL_Audit_Report/ path .
#author          :Prabash
#date            :20170902
#================================



true > /home/cmb/SL__scripts/Prabash/list2.txt

read -p "Enter Date " n

ls -lrt /nrtrdepath/ | awk {'print $9'} | grep AuditReport_SL_nrtrde_$n.csv >> /home/cmb/SL__scripts/Prabash/list2.txt
ls -lrt /dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/ | awk {'print $9'} | grep  AuditReport_SL_ICT_$n.csv.gz >> /home/cmb/SL__scripts/Prabash/list2.txt
ls -lrt /dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/ | awk {'print $9'} | grep  AuditReport_SL_BI_$n.csv.gz >> /home/cmb/SL__scripts/Prabash/list2.txt

k=`cat /home/cmb/SL__scripts/Prabash/list2.txt`

while IFS= read -r k ; do
if [[ $k == AuditReport_SL_nrtrde* ]] ; then
    scp /nrtrdepath/$k cmb@172.23.1.136:/tmp/SL_Audit_Report/
    else
    for i in $k; do scp /dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/$i cmb@172.23.1.136:/tmp/SL_Audit_Report/
fi
done
```

Comment: Where is the input for `k` supposed to come from? User input in the terminal?

Comment: @Hauke Laging  no, k suppose to be the variable i am assigning to contents of text file.

Comment: @Hauke Laging insted of this "filename="/home/cmb/SL__scripts/Prabash/list2.txt"" i can assign it as 
 below right ...k=`cat /home/cmb/SL__scripts/Prabash/list2.txt

Comment: There's a stray `done` at the end of one of the `scp` lines.

Comment: @Prabash If you get error messages when running this, you should mention them in the question. That helps us helping you.

Comment: @Kusalananda it is work fine until while loop, I am very new to the reading text file and using conditioning file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is pick three file based on a date string and `scp` these to another location.  This may be done with

```
#!/bin/sh

thedate="$1"

scp "/nrtrdepath/AuditReport_SL_nrtrde_$thedate.csv" \
    "/dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/AuditReport_SL_ICT_$thedate.csv.gz" \
    "/dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/AuditReport_SL_BI_$thedate.csv.gz" \
    cmb@172.23.1.136:/tmp/SL_Audit_Report/
```

You would run this with

```
$ sh ./script "datestring"
```

where `datestring` is the string that you want to use as the date in the filename.

This works since `scp` can copy several files to a single location, just like `cp`.

With some error checking:

```
#!/bin/sh

thedate="$1"

if [ ! -f "/nrtrdepath/AuditReport_SL_nrtrde_$thedate.csv" ]; then
    printf 'AuditReport_SL_nrtrde_%s.csv is missing\n' "$thedate" >&2
    do_exit=1
fi
if [ ! -f "/dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/AuditReport_SL_ICT_$thedate.csv.gz" ]; then
    printf 'AuditReport_SL_ICT_%s.csv is missing\n' "$thedate" >&2
    do_exit=1
fi
if [ ! -f "/dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/AuditReport_SL_BI_$thedate.csv.gz" ]; then
    printf 'AuditReport_SL_BI_%s.csv is missing\n' "$thedate" >&2
    do_exit=1
fi

if [ "$do_exit" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo 'Some files are missing, exiting' >&2
    exit 1
fi

if ! scp "/nrtrdepath/AuditReport_SL_nrtrde_$thedate.csv" \
         "/dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/AuditReport_SL_ICT_$thedate.csv.gz" \
         "/dcs/SL_AUDIT_REPORT/AuditReport_SL_BI_$thedate.csv.gz" \
         cmb@172.23.1.136:/tmp/SL_Audit_Report/
then
    echo 'Errors executing scp' >&2
else
    echo 'Transfer is done.'
fi
```

Comment: thanks for qucick solution. really appreciate it, yes  i need to scp files based on file name which include date it self.  for your solution i shoud run the script like this:
 sh ./script 20170905
 correct if iam wrong .
 note : files containsdate in this foramt YYMMDD 
 Eg:
 AuditReport_SL_ICT_20170905.csv.gz

Comment: @Prabash Yes, that looks correct to me, if you meant `YYYYMMDD`, rather than `YYMMDD`.

Comment: @Prabash If you want todays date, always, use `thedate=$(date +%Y%m%d)` in the script rather than `thedate="$1"`. And then don't give a date on the command line.

Comment: yes it should be YYYYMMDD ,my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variable assignments in a file then you can activate these by sourcing that file:

```
source /path/to/config_file
```

Comment: no need of to adding to source i think. here in as k, i am assigning  to file contents (3 file names ). please find updated code in above .please point out any mistake i have done .

Comment: I wonder if this answer is even attached to the correct question...

Comment: @Kusalananda I do admit that I had (and have) difficulties understanding the OP what the problem is. My answer refers to "I am struggling with reading constants from file". But I admire your effort...

Comment: @HaukeLaging Ah, my apologies. I saw another question referring to reading from config files, and thought you'd accidentally answered the wrong one...